# PHP File Copy Permission Error

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

Why am I getting a permission error on the line were I copy the file across?

I have `print_r` on  `$candidatefile` and this shows the full file path and correct name to the new location.

`$fields['Resume']` is blank when I run `print_r` but the file still uploads to the cache

both folders are `777`

/home/name/mysite0912/cache/resumes/1ZHiYGZj7J.txt Remuse
/home/name/mysite0912/downloads/cv_folder/new-filename-cv.txt New Location

Everything else is sweet except that

**Code Section:**

```
  $candidateuploaddir = _MYSITEDIR . '/downloads/refocus_candidates/';
        $candiatefilename = $fields['RenamedResume'];
        $candidatefile = $candidateuploaddir . $candiatefilename;

        if(empty($fields['Resume']))
        {
                echo 'null';
        }else{
        copy($fields['Resume'],$candiatefilename);
        }
```

**Upload Function:**

```
function uploadResume()
{
    if (!isset($_FILES['UploadResume'])) return false;
    $uploaddir = _CACHEDIR.'/resumes/';
    /* create the upload folder if it does not already exist */
    CMS::RecursiveMkdir($uploaddir);
    $extension = CMS::getFileExtension(basename($_FILES['UploadResume']['name']));
    /* keep producing random filenames until we get a unique one */
    while (empty($filename) || CMS::fileExists($uploaddir.$filename)) {
        $filename = CMS::randomString(10).'.'.$extension;
    }

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadResume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){

        return $uploadfile;
        //$uploadfile;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**On Submit Line:**

```
$fields['Resume'] = CMS::either(CMS_Plugin_plugin_jobs_apply::uploadResume(), CMS::getFormData('Resume', false)); //upload resume to temporary location
```

Comment: @ColeJohnson Warning: copy(name) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in .php on line 197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So us a print_r of ($_FILES);  have you set the enctype of the form to allow files uploads ?

before this line, add:

```
copy($fields['Resume'],$candiatefilename);


file_exists($fields['Resume']) or die('can not copy file '.$fields['Resume'].' because it does not  exist !'); 

// else 
copy($fields['Resume'],$candiatefilename);
```

Comment: `Array ( [UploadResume] => Array ( [name] => coverLetter_Aug 16.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpYVg6Ny [error] => 0 [size] => 629 ) )` did not die and got the error again.  I have just been adding on to the code originally it was sent via email